# Regex for multiple date formats

Tags: python, regex, pandas, date

What regex can match this date format: Oct,16 , 2012 ?

I have a pandas series that looks like this:

```
0             2012-05-25 00:00:00
1             2012-08-28 00:00:00
2             2012-08-22 00:00:00
3             2012-10-16 00:00:00
4    Oct, 16 , 2012/ Nov, 1, 2012
5             2012-05-20 00:00:00
6             2012-10-30 00:00:00
7             2012-11-12 00:00:00
8             2012-12-04 00:00:00
9            12/4/2012, 16/4/2012
```

I am looking to extract the different dates from the rows 4 and 9 and put them in a list.
I am thinking regex is the right way to go but I have trouble finding the regex I need for Oct,16 , 2012.
Any ideas ?

Comment: `.*` matches that string. Please add your attempt to the question - would also help if you explain why you're parsing dates with a regex, like why _wouldn't_ you use [dateutil.parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html)?

Comment: Sorry: "I am looking to extract the different dates from the rows 4 and 9 and put them in a list" is not clear as the dates there have formats other than `Oct,16 , 2012`

Comment: Please edit the question to remove the [x/y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and focus on the thing you're trying to solve - don't forget the title :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a regex for the initial division; you can `.split()` the string

Once you have the pairs, then you can use a regex to validate it or attempt to parse 'em into dates

```py
value.split("/" if value.count("/") == 1 else ",")
```

example use

```py
>>> value.split("/" if value.count("/") == 1 else ",")
['Oct, 16 , 2012', ' Nov, 1, 2012']
>>> value = "12/4/2012, 16/4/2012"
>>> value.split("/" if value.count("/") == 1 else ",")
['12/4/2012', ' 16/4/2012']
```

If you could have a collection of divisors, you could generate a best-fit (else `raise StopIteration`)

```py
next(x for x in (",", "/", "-") if value.count(x) == 1)
```

all together in a gross 1-liner

```py
df["B"] = df["A"].apply(lambda r: r.split(next(x for x in (" ", ",", "/", "-") if r.count(x) == 1))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing dates with regex is normally discouraged. If for some reason you do need regex for the task, try this:

```
[A-za-z]{3},\d{2},\s\d{4}
```

This matches a string that:

- `[A-za-z]{3}` starts with exactly three alphabetic (lower- or upper-case)chars followed by
- `,` a comma
- `\d{2}` exactly two digits
- `,` a comma
- `\s` one whitespace char (as in the example posted) and
- `\d{4}` exactly four digits

Comment: Thx ! not really what I am looking for, I edited the question to clarify my purpose